# Highlight Selected row in MvcContrib Grid using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, mvccontrib, mvccontrib-grid

I am new to MVC and jQuery. I have a MvcContrib Grid. I have a select link that selects the row to bring data so I already have a function on that click. Can I add a selected row highlight to the same function. Here's a snippet of how my code looks like.

```
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(column =>
{
  column.Custom(@<a href='#@item.ID' onclick='getContactDetails(@item.ID); 
  return false;'>Select</a>);
  column.For(x => Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Contact", new { id = x.ID, 
  socialcommunityid = x.SocialCommunityID },new { @class = "openDialog", data_dialog_id 
  = "editContactDialog", data_dialog_title = "Contact Details" }) 
  ).Named("").Sortable(false);
})


//This is the function that is already present
function getContactDetails(communityContactID)
{
  //Some code to fetch data
}
```

Can someone help me to highlight the selected row?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new css class with required styles in it. Add this class to the currnet row inside click handler. Pass another parameter `this` to `getContactDetails` which will help us to get the corresponding row. Try this.

Css

```
.selected{
    background: "someColor";
}
```

Js

```
function getContactDetails(communityContactID, obj)
{
    //This will remove selected class from previous selection
    $(this).closest('table').find('tr').removeClass('selected');

    //This will add the selected class to current row
    $(this).closest('tr').addClass('selected');

    //Some code to fetch data
}
```

Comment: I tried your method by passing the following parameter: column.Custom(@<a href='#@item.ID' onclick='getContactDetails(@item.ID,this); return false;'>Select</a>); and added your lines and parameters to my function but this doesn't highlight the row. Also it has stopped the data fetch operation which was after the code for highlight. Any advice?

Comment: I changed m\the code in function Get Contact details to obj.parents('table').find('.selected').removeClass("selected");
        obj.parents('tr').addClass("selected"); and have the      gridrow alternate getting highlighted. But the other rows are left unhighlighted. Any suggestions?